# Add buttons above scroll (I guess you can't teach an old dog new tricks! )

Tags: button, layout, menu, scroll

ON SUNDAY I ACTUALLY SIDE-LOADED MY FIRST APP!!!  Simple, unfinished, couple bugs, but it works.

My opening screen (XML: "event_list.xml") is a scroll list - select one get detail screen.
XML looks like:  (This code is still a fragment.)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <fragment 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:name="com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListFragment"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

And the row (XML "event_row.xml") looks like:

```
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:padding="2dip" />
```

I want a couple buttons at the top above the scroll.  The best I can do is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btn_Add"
          android:text="@string/add"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </fragment>
```

But the button overlays the first entry!
What ties the row to the list screen and how do I get two buttons above the scroll (rows)?

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <Button  android:id="@+id/btn_Add"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"   
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:text="@string/add" />

  <Button  android:id="@+id/btn_Exit"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Add" 
    android:text="@string/exit" />

  <Button  android:id="@+id/btn_Other"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Exit" 
    android:text="@string/other" />

 <fragment
    android:name="com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Add"  />
 </RelativeLayout>   

   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:padding="2dip" />
<!-- This defines a row in which text can be placed -->
<!--   "text1" is the IDof the view for loading the list with data -->
```

Now just need to make the button code copied from detail screen (activity only) work in list screen (w/ fragment):
This generates errors:  (findViewById undefined)

```
  mExitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Exit);
```

This crashed:

```
  mExitButton = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_Exit);
```

Still working in this (it's late):

```
   View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.????????, container, false);
```